# Suggestion on how to get illustrative images legally

Tags: discussion, answers

From time to time when answering I so badly want to link in an image of a product to illustrate what kind of product I'm talking about. However I agree that we should not do product recommendations, neither directly (through links to online stores) or by referencing product names/sites/...

In addition you have the licensing issue of just pulling some random image of the net, and including it in your answer.

So my question is: *What do you do when you want to illustrate your answer with some product, without endorsing that product, or illustration*?

On a sidenote: *How do we handle images which are clearly lifted from a random website, without clear licensing?*

Currently my attempt at doing this somewhat correctly, is to include links to google searches. Here is an example link looking for [illustrative images](//google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=illustrative+images):

```
http://google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=illustrative+images
```

However this is an external link, and the answer doesn't have the catchy image to illustrate my intended solution. *Do you have any suggestions on how to get illustrative images legally?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

---

## Using Images

---

> What do you do when you want to illustrate your answer with some product.

**Use them.**

The use of images we "lift from a random website" is almost definitely covered under [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use). Use however, should be attributed.

**1. Purpose and character of the use**

> for the enrichment of the general public  .. [and not] for reasons of personal profit

Although we get precious reputation for posting questions and answers, I don't think this counts legally as profit.

**2. Nature of the copyrighted work**

> consider certain aspects of the work to be relevant

Try to post *relevant* images

**3. Amount and substantiality**

> the quantity or percentage of the original copyrighted work that has been imported into the new work

This is unlikely to be a problem, we're copying a few images, not a product's design.

**4. Effect upon work's value**

> specific use of the work has significantly harmed the copyright owner's market

If anything, we're providing a small benefit by essentially advertising specific products.

---

## Endorsement

---

> ...without endorsing that product, or illustration

This is a bit trickier, but I would say **"Don't worry about it"**. Just pick an image that best illustrates what point you want to convey.

If a user is clearly **endorsing** a product, especially their own, I'd raise a spam flag.

---

## Attribution

---

> How do we handle images which are clearly lifted from a random website, without clear licensing?

If we assume that we can use the images with fair use, then licensing isn't a problem, but attribution still is. For an image used without attribution, I'd suggest leaving a comment asking the OP to properly attribute it. It's worth noting however, that a lot of users (myself included) often simply *forget*, so I'd keep the comment light in tone.

Comment: True. I try to add a website that I got the image from and clearly say that I do not own it.

Comment: (1) Stack Exchange is redistributing the content for profit. (3) The photos are often the *complete* work themselves, which (4) is often stock photography intended for this very purpose and thereby being directly devalued. Justifications for Fair Use typical include a meta level (criticism, comparison, commentary, reporting of *the work itself*) which is absent here. IANAL but this is definitely not a clear-cut case of fair use.

Answer (score 3):

In google image search you can use search tools to filter image results only to display images which are marked as free for use.

For search with URL I have found the following cases:

1. Labeled for reuse

   http://google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=illustrative+images&tbs=sur:fc
2. Labeled for reuse with modification

   http://google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=illustrative+images&tbs=sur:fmc
3. Labeled for noncommercial reuse with modification

   http://google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=illustrative+images&tbs=sur:fm
4. Labeled for noncommercial reuse

   http://google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=illustrative+images&tbs=sur:f

I always prefer to take the camera and make my own picture or if impossible I can draw the thing I want to show.

Comment: How do you specify that you only want images marked as free for use? And can that easily used in a google link?

Comment: @holroy maybe it is advanced image search -> usage rights. I have to check, my google is not in english and I can't tell you exactly what to click.

Comment: @holroy  at the end of url `http://google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=illustrative+images` you have to use one of these `&tbs=sur:fc` or `&tbs=sur:fmc` or `&tbs=sur:fm`  or  `&tbs=sur:f` for different rights